# What would you be guily for legally killing someone using illegal means?

Tags: law-in-fiction, weapons, defense-of-others

The situation in question is similar to a scene from the TV show Burn Notice.

Micheal is being held hostage, at gun point, by an old enemy, Larry. Fiona rightfully believes that Larry is about to kill Micheal. Fiona attempts to kill Larry with a rifle but discovers the buildings windows are bulletproof. She then decides to place a small C4 explosive device on the window near Larry and detonated it, killing him and saving Micheal. Assuming Larry's death is, and can be proven to be, self-defence/defence-of-others, what would Fiona be guilty of? I believe C4 is illegal to buy, own and use by civilians, so even with it being a lawful killing, what would Fiona be guilty of?

Comment: @Jen - Maybe, I'm just wondering if the involvement of explosives would make a difference.  Are you saying it would be the same as that other question in that he wouldn't be charged with murder but would likely be charged independently with the possession and use of explosives?

Answer (score 1):

*"It was necessary to break this law in order to save this persons life."* is, if truthful and convincing, a pretty broad defense. The main exception is that you may only kill an attacker to save the potential victim, not an uninvolved person.

As such, setting off the explosion would be covered by self defence clauses. However, if Fiona already had the C4 prior to the emergency situation, the usual laws clarifying who is and who is not allowed to own explosives apply. If the C4 was just there and Fiona only took it in that very moment, she's fine.